# How to get first or any 3 rows of all unique IDs?

Tags: mysql-5.7

Sample Table

```
╔════╤═══════╗
║ id │ value ║
╠════╪═══════╣
║ 1  │ a     ║
╟────┼───────╢
║ 1  │ b     ║
╟────┼───────╢
║ 1  │ c     ║
╟────┼───────╢
║ 1  │ d     ║
╟────┼───────╢
║ 2  │ e     ║
╟────┼───────╢
║ 2  │ f     ║
╟────┼───────╢
```

Expected Output

```
╔════╤═══════╗
║ id │ value ║
╠════╪═══════╣
║ 1  │ a     ║
╟────┼───────╢
║ 1  │ b     ║
╟────┼───────╢
║ 1  │ c     ║
╟────┼───────╢
║ 2  │ e     ║
╟────┼───────╢
║ 2  │ f     ║
╟────┼───────╢
```

Something like this. If there's less than 3 values, still get whatever rows for that particular ID.
I tried using nested selects and limit but it didn't work.
MYSQL 5.7

Thanks

Comment: I removed the "Windows" tag because your question is not Windows-specific.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL 8+, then `ROW_NUMBER` would work here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id, value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY value) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT id, value
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= 3
ORDER BY id, value;
```

[image: screen capture of demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: Hi, thanks for the fast reply! But I'm using MySQL 5.7:/

Comment: This query is difficult to handle in MySQL 5.7.  You should upgrade if you can.